# fullpage.js how to attach fixed menu to second section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

By default, menu appears on every page. I want to make the menu not to appear on first page. I did the following:

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 600,
    css3: true,
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if (index == 2 && direction == 'up'){
            $('#menu').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        if (index == 2){
            $('#menu').css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }
```

Now the menu appears when I scroll to the second page and hides when I scroll to the first page. But in this way the menu is not the part of second page, it just changes visibility depending on position.

I want the following: when it scrolls to the first page, the menu should stay on the second. And conversely, when it scrolls from the first page to the second, the menu should be on the second page.

P.S. Now in html, menu is placed outside the full page wrapper.

P.P.S. The website will have more than two pages and I want to attach menu to the top of the window.

P.P.P.S. I've done what I wanted. But it works bad - http://jsfiddle.net/a3dw6p4w/

Answer (score 0):

> I want the following: when it scrolls to the first page, the menu should stay on the second.

Use a fixed position for the menu. That's a thing for CSS, not for jQuery:

```
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, in my question I forgot to tell about one important detail - the website will have more than two pages and I want to make the menu appear on all pages and attach it to the top of the window.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?? That'd fix the problem. It is FIXED.

Comment: it doesn't work. The menu is only on the second page. When I scroll to the third page, the menu stays on second page.

Comment: Then its because you are doing somethign wrong... Just check the example in http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/, look at the source code and you will find my exact same solution.

Comment: You are probably not applying the style properly.

Comment: I answered your question. But you are not doing it correctly... you are using two menu elements instead of one... etc. I have no more time to spend on this question. I gave you the solution already. The rest are other problems you are having. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 1200,
    css3: true,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        if (index > 1){
            $('#menu').fadeTo("slow",1);
        }
    },
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if (index == 2 && direction == 'up') {
            $('#menu').fadeTo("slow",0);
        }
    }
  });
    });
</script>
```

It says that if on page load, if you scroll to a section below (index > 1), then the menu will fade in slowly.

Then, if you scroll up from the second section (i.e. to section 1), it will fade out slowly.